# Infusionsoft - Adding a Contact to a Company using the API

Tags: php, infusionsoft

I'm using novaksolution's [Infusionsoft SDK](https://github.com/novaksolutions/infusionsoft-php-sdk) and trying to add a *Contact* to a *Company* by setting the `Company` and `CompanyID` fields.

All other fields are updating without issue, but the `CompanyID` field always comes back as 0.

For example:

```
$contact = new Infusionsoft_Contact(1234);
$contact->CompanyID = 5678;
$contact->Company = 'Test Company Name';

// update other fields
$contact->save();

// Shows CompanyID = 5678
var_dump($contact);

$contact = new Infusionsoft_Contact(1234);

// All other fields updated; CompanyID is 0
var_dump($contact);
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this took me longer to figure out than it should have.

For anyone else stuck on this, you need to set the field `AccountId`, not `CompanyID`.